# merging two objects of strings. java

Tags: java, string, list

I have an assignment that requires me to make ordered string list objects.
i currently have 2 ordered string lists, each with 7 string values in them. 
im trying to create a method that merges list myList and yourList into a combined list combinedList.

here is what i have so far.

```
public boolean merge(OrderedStringList myList, OrderedStringList yourList){
    int index;
    String value;
    for (index = 0;index < numUsed; index++){
        value = myList.storage[index];
        combinedList.insert(value);
    }
    for (index = 0;index < numUsed; index++){
        value = yourList.storage[index];
        combinedList.insert(value);
    }

}
```

i declare the object combinedList in my main, and it doesnt recognize it in my orderedStringList.class

the insert function will insert strings into alphabetical order.

Comment: try to pass it as a parameter of your orderedStringList.class.

Comment: Are you saying you're declaring a variable in one method and trying to access it in another? If so, that's not possible because those scopes do not intersect.

Answer (score 0):

Where exactly is `combinedList` declared? Perhaps you should declare it outside outside your method so that all the methods can access it.

```
public class Merger {
    private OrderedStringList combinedList; // This is a field
    private int numUsed;
    public static void main(){
        new Merger().merge(new OrderedStringList(),new OrderedStringList());
    }
    public boolean merge(OrderedStringList myList, OrderedStringList yourList){
        int index;
        String value;
        for (index = 0;index < numUsed; index++){
            value = myList.storage[index];
            combinedList.insert(value);
        }
        for (index = 0;index < numUsed; index++){
            value = yourList.storage[index];
            combinedList.insert(value);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
class OrderedStringList {
    public String[] storage;
    public void insert(String value) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you declared the `combinedList` inside your main function, it is accessible only inside the main function.

What you should do is create the `combinedList` inside the above function and return the result to the calling function i.e. your `main` function.

Answer (score 0):

Found out how to fix my problem. I just called the insert function based on the amount of strings that were in each list, and added them to the new combined list.

```
public boolean merge(OrderedStringList myList, OrderedStringList yourList) {
    boolean result = false;
    int index;
    for (index = 0; index < myList.numUsed; index++) {
        Insert(myList.storage[index]);
        result = true;
    }
    for (index = 0; index < yourList.numUsed; index++) {
        Insert(yourList.storage[index]);
        result = true;
    }
    return result;
}
```